# How to return an entity by property if it already exists?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
public class Language {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 2)
    private String code; //EN, DE, US

    public Language(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}

@Entity
public class ProductText {
    @OneToOne(Cascade.ALL)
    private Language lang;
}

ProductText text = new ProductText();
text.setLang(new Language("en")); //what if "en" exists?
dao.save(text);
```

Now, when I persist the `ProductText`, everytime a new `Language` object would be generated.

Can I prevent this, and in case a language table entry with `code = 'en'` exists this existing entity should be linked instead.

My initial goal is to not having to repeat the countryCodeString "EN" multiple times in my product-text table, but just reference the id. But does this really make sense? Should I rather just use the plain `String` without an extra table? (I later want to query a list of productTexts `where lang = 'de'`).

Is the only change executing a select like `dao.findByLang("en")` before?
Or is there also some hibernate feature that would support this without explicit executing a query myself?

Answer (score 1):

Do you process the value "en" further or do you display it directly? If only used for displaying purposes, I would just store the string, but if you want to reduce redundancy by using foreign key IDs you *have* to create an `Entity` containing the language string `en` which can be persisted via entity manager and which you have to obtain out of the entity manager before persisting to reuse it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only three different possible values for the language, you can also use an enum like this :

```
public enum Language {

    EN("EN"),
    DE("DE"),
    US("US");

    private String code; //EN, DE, US

    public Language(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    // Getter...
}

@Entity
public class ProductText {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    // Or @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Language lang;
}
```

`EnumType.STRING` will store the enum in the database as a String, while `EnumType.ORDINAL` will store it as an int. Int is maybe a little more efficient, but the mapping could change if you insert a new value in your enum. String is more flexible since it will use the names of your enum members.

In both case, you don't have to manage a separate entity and hibernate will not create an additional table, and it's more type-safe than using a plain string.

Answer (score 0):

If the only value in Language is a 2 or 3 letter string, why not just have the string as a member? This will be quicker and more efficient.

Comment: Yes that would be possible, with the drawback having dedundant 2 letter codes in each entity, instead of just a foreign key. The question is: what is the better waY?